# Jenkins won't install recommended plugins on Windows

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to run Jenkins on my Windows laptop using their `.war` package. The Java version I have installed is `jdk-11.0.12`, and as far as I saw, Java 11 is supported by Jenkins.

After running the `java -jar jenkins.war` command, everything works fine (connecting to localhost:8080 and entering the `initialAdminPassword`).

The problem comes when deciding what plugins to install. I clicked on the option that lets Jenkins automatically install the recommended plugins for me, but, unfortunately, all of these plugins seem to fail installing:

[image]

This is a part of my log:

```
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to load https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/token-macro/267.vcdaea6462991/token-macro.hpi to C:\Users\uie51265\.jenkins\plugins\token-macro.jpi.tmp
        at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1300)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to download from https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/token-macro/267.vcdaea6462991/token-macro.hpi (redirected to: https://get.jenkins.io/plugins/token-macro/267.vcdaea6462991/token-macro.hpi)
        at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1334)
        at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1888)
        at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:2198)
        at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1862)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:121)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Does anyone have an idea what the problem can be? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems likely to be a [proxy error](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/JenkinsBehindProxy).

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem: I tried to import into java keychain all jenkins certificates but no luck. I had java JDK11.0.1

I solved by installing JRE8, the jre1.8.0_331 to be precise.

You then have to change `C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jenkins.xml` for pointing to jre8 and also firewall exception named jenkins: firewall > advanced settings > Inbound rules > jenkins > right click: properties > Programs and Services.